# MySQL: error on El Capitan OS after Yosemite OS update

Tags: mysql-error-1064, pid, osx-elcapitan

I have problems with MySQL on my MacBook. I had updated my OS from Yosemite to El Capitan before I installed MySQL server.

Now, when I try to run MySQL on Terminal, I got the error like this

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

Anyone can help me please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give us some more background (are your running MAMP)? etc.

Answer (score 5):

Try updating your my.cnf file to set the location of the PID file manually. Here's how you do that.

In your Terminal run the following command.

```
ps -ax | grep mysql
```

This will list all the locations of the important mysql files. Look for the path of the --pid-file

I will look something like this:

```
--pid-file=/path/to/your/local/mysqld.local.pid
```

Copy the path of the mysqld.local.pid file

Next open your my.cnf file using nano

```
sudo nano /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf
```

Set the pid-file path at the end of your my.cnf file. Search for pid-file. If you can't find it, manually enter it at the end of your my.cnf file. This will tell mysql where to look for the PID file. Enter the path that you copied like the example below.

```
pid-file = /path/to/your/local/mysqld.local.pid
```

Close and save the file

Next restart mysql. You may need to do this twice to reset your PID error.

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

That should solve your problem! Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot... After I updated the OS again, the problem was fixed. Anw, thanks

Comment: in mac El Capitain, the path was /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid. And there was no my.cnf. So I had to create new in /etc/my.cnf

Then I added,

[mysqld]
pid-file =/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the file my.cnf in /etc and add [mysqld] before the line pid-file = /path/to/your/local/mysqld.local.pid
Finally it worked!