# How to install MySQL on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)?

Tags: mysql, macos

I am following [this guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/) to install MySQL, Apache and Phpmyadmin on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

I have not upgraded to El Captain — instead, I have done a complete clean reinstall.

When I try to run MySQL (using `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`) I get the following error message:

```
Starting MySQL
..................................................................................................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

I tried the advice in this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225652/mysql-error-on-el-capitan-os-after-yosemite-os-update), and I got the following error message:

```
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

I note that the latest version of MySQL is for 10.10, while the guide mentions 10.9. So I tried uninstalling mySQL using the steps in [this guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x). I then installed the MySQL for 10.9, but it is the same problem.

[This guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/mysql-error-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/) recommends repairing disk permissions. I booted into recovery from a USB pen drive, and repaired permissions, but still the same problem.

Comment: What are lines 1 to ...5(?) of /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf ? Does it start like the example "Here is a typical global option file" at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html , i.e. with a `[group]` like `[client]` or `[mysql]`?

Comment: When I enter `usr/local/mysql/my.cnf` in the terminal it says `-bash: usr/local/mysql/my.cnf: No such file or directory`.

Comment: And when you enter `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`? Even better: `less /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`.

Comment: (1) `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf` - gives `-bash: /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf: Permission denied`

(2) `less /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf` - gives `pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid 
/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf (END)`